# Python 3.6.4 doesn't have tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a script that uses pymsgbox to prompt a user for input and am getting an error: `Tkinter is required for pymsgbox`. I have tried `import tkinter` and checked in the folder `C:\Python36\Lib` for `tkinter.py` but it's not there. I have tried `pip install tkinter` and other things I found on Google, but am unable to find the module and continue with my work. I have also tried to repair my Python installation, but the module is still missing.

Any help or advice is appreciated. I am using Python 3.6.4, PyMsgBox 1.0.6 by the way.

Comment: _"checked in the folder C:\Python36\Lib for tkinter.py but it's not there."_ I think that's normal. I have tkinter installed and I don't have a Lib/tkitner.py file either. But I do have a Lib/tkinter directory. Do you have that directory?

Comment: No, it's not in my Lib folder.

Comment: probably you are installing tkinter for python2. Have you tried `pip3 install tkinter`?

Comment: Python 3 should come with "t"kinter. Python2 was the one with "T"kinter. Looking at https://github.com/asweigart/PyMsgBox/blob/master/setup.py tells that it has no support for Python3.6. Maybe that is your issue

Comment: PyMsgBox should support python 3.x. Seems the problem is with the python installation. With python 3.6 on windows `import tkinter` should work out of the box, since tkinter is in the standard library. If something's wrong with your python installation, you could try reinstalling python. https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

Comment: TK is not packaged in pypi. https://pypi.org/project/tkinter3000/#description. You cannot pip install it.

Comment: I only have Python 3.6.4 installed, and I tried repairing the installation. Would the only solution be to install a version of Python2?