# How do you combine 2 python scripts with import?

Tags: python

I have 2 scripts, one that plays hangman in the GUI module tkinter, and another that will be a main menu. This is the hangman one.

```
def hangman():
    restart_var = True
    while restart_var:
        counter = 0
        ans = ''

        #assign input to answer and close window
        def confirmAnswer(ans,guessing_word_input):
            global answer
            answer = (guessing_word_input.get()).upper()
            first_window.destroy()

        #Random Word for solo play
        def soloPlay():
            random_word_list = ['COMPUTER','PYTHON','CODING','KEYBOARD','MOUSE','MONITOR','TELEVISION','POPCORN','BURGER','MUSIC','HANGMAN','FOOTBALL','TELEPHONE','SMARTPHONE','CAMERA']
            random.shuffle(random_word_list)
            global answer
            answer = random_word_list[0]
            first_window.destroy()

        #First window to enter word
        first_window = Tk()
        first_window.title('Enter Word')
        first_window.resizable(False,False)

        #text
        enter_word_label = Label(text = 'Enter Guessing Word (letters only, spaces allowed) : ')
        enter_word_label.pack()

        #input box
        guessing_word_input = Entry(first_window,show = '*',width = (50))
        guessing_word_input.pack(side = LEFT)

        #confirm button
        confirm_guess_button = Button(text = 'Enter',command = (lambda: confirmAnswer(ans,guessing_word_input)))
        confirm_guess_button.pack(side = LEFT)

        #solo play button
        solo_play_button = Button(text = 'Solo',command = soloPlay)
        solo_play_button.pack(side = RIGHT)

        first_window.mainloop()

        #open main window
        window = Tk()
        window.geometry('800x600')
        window.title('Hangman')
        window.resizable(False,False)
        answerList = []

        #turns string to list of letters
        for i in answer:
            answerList.append(i)

        #creates string of stars
        revealing_ans = []
        for i in range(len(answerList)):
            if answerList[i]!=' ':
                revealing_ans += '*'
            else:
                revealing_ans += '/'
        print(revealing_ans)

        #creates reavealing answer label
        revealing_ans_label = Label(text= revealing_ans,font = (None,50))
        revealing_ans_label.pack()
        print(len(revealing_ans),' letters\n')

        #create exit button
        exit_button = Button(text = 'EXIT',command = exit)
        exit_button.place(x = 20,y =20)

        hangman_canvas = Canvas(window,width = 400,height = 400,)
        hangman_canvas.place(x=200,y=70)

        #class for life and turn counter
        class turn:
            def __init__(self,num):
                self.num = num

            def lifeLost(self):
                self.num -=1

            def turn(self):
                self.num += 1

        #life counter label
        lifenum = turn(8)
        life_label_text = 'Lives: ' + str(lifenum.num)
        life_label = Label(text = life_label_text,font = (None, 20),foreground = 'red')
        life_label.place(x = 650,y = 50)

        #turn counter label
        num_of_turns = turn(0)
        num_of_turns_text = 'Turns: ' + str(num_of_turns.num)
        num_of_turns_label = Label(text = num_of_turns_text,font = (None, 20))
        num_of_turns_label.place(x = 650,y = 100)

        #checks if guess is in answer, updates turn and life counter, disables button pressed, ends game if complete or no lives left
        class button:
            def __init__(self,letter,button):
                num_of_turns.turn()
                num_of_turns_text = 'Turns: ' + str(num_of_turns.num)
                num_of_turns_label.config(text = num_of_turns_text)
                self.letter = letter
                self.button = button
                button.config(state = 'disabled',disabledforeground = 'red2')
                print(letter)
                counter =0
                #check for letter
                for i in range(len(answerList)):
                    if letter == answerList[i]:
                        revealing_ans[i]=answerList[i]
                        counter += 1
                if counter > 0:
                    print('Correct')
                    #update revealing answer
                    revealing_ans_label.config(text = revealing_ans)
                    #checks for *, ends game
                    if '*' not in revealing_ans:
                        endGame()
                else:
                    print('Wrong')
                    lifenum.lifeLost()
                    life_label_text = 'Lives: ' + str(lifenum.num)
                    life_label.config(text = life_label_text)

                    if lifenum.num == 7:
                        hangman_canvas.create_line(0,300,80,300)
                    if lifenum.num == 6:
                        shape2 = hangman_canvas.create_line(40,40,40,300)
                    if lifenum.num == 5:
                        shape3 = hangman_canvas.create_line(0,40,300,40)
                    if lifenum.num == 4:
                        shape4 = hangman_canvas.create_line(300,40,300,100)
                    if lifenum.num == 3:
                        shape5 = hangman_canvas.create_oval(260,100,340,180)
                    if lifenum.num == 2:
                        shape6 = hangman_canvas.create_line(300,180,300,260)
                    if lifenum.num == 1:
                        shape7 = hangman_canvas.create_line(280,220,300,200,320,220)
                    if lifenum.num == 0:
                        shape8 = hangman_canvas.create_line(280,280,300,260,320,280)
                        endGame()


        #final window, shows answer in red or green, play again, exit buttons
        def endGame():
            print(answer)
            window.destroy()
            final_window = Tk()
            final_window.title('GAME ENDED')
            final_message = Label(text = 'GAME ENDED')
            final_message.pack()
            answer_label = Label(final_window,text= answer,font = (None,50))
            if lifenum.num == 0:
                answer_label.config(foreground = 'red')
            else:
                answer_label.config(foreground = 'green')
            answer_label.pack()
            exit_button_end = Button(final_window,text = 'EXIT',command = (lambda: exit()))
            exit_button_end.pack()

            play_again_button = Button(text = 'Play Again',command = final_window.destroy)
            play_again_button.pack()

        #create frame for buttons
        button_frame = Frame()
        button_frame.place(x=0, y = 500)

        buta = Button(button_frame,text = 'A',command =(lambda: button('A',buta)),width = 3)
        buta.pack(side = LEFT)
        butb = Button(button_frame,text = 'B',command =(lambda: button('B',butb)),width = 3)
        butb.pack(side = LEFT)
        butc = Button(button_frame,text = 'C',command =(lambda: button('C',butc)),width = 3)
        butc.pack(side = LEFT)
        butd = Button(button_frame,text = 'D',command =(lambda: button('D',butd)),width = 3)
        butd.pack(side = LEFT)
        bute = Button(button_frame,text = 'E',command =(lambda: button('E',bute)),width = 3)
        bute.pack(side = LEFT)
        butf = Button(button_frame,text = 'F',command =(lambda: button('F',butf)),width = 3)
        butf.pack(side = LEFT)
        butg = Button(button_frame,text = 'G',command =(lambda: button('G',butg)),width = 3)
        butg.pack(side = LEFT)
        buth = Button(button_frame,text = 'H',command =(lambda: button('H',buth)),width = 3)
        buth.pack(side = LEFT)
        buti = Button(button_frame,text = 'I',command =(lambda: button('I',buti)),width = 3)
        buti.pack(side = LEFT)
        butj = Button(button_frame,text = 'J',command =(lambda: button('J',butj)),width = 3)
        butj.pack(side = LEFT)
        butk = Button(button_frame,text = 'K',command =(lambda: button('K',butk)),width = 3)
        butk.pack(side = LEFT)
        butl = Button(button_frame,text = 'L',command =(lambda: button('L',butl)),width = 3)
        butl.pack(side = LEFT)
        butm = Button(button_frame,text = 'M',command =(lambda: button('M',butm)),width = 3)
        butm.pack(side = LEFT)
        butn = Button(button_frame,text = 'N',command =(lambda: button('N',butn)),width = 3)
        butn.pack(side = LEFT)
        buto = Button(button_frame,text = 'O',command =(lambda: button('O',buto)),width = 3)
        buto.pack(side = LEFT)
        butp = Button(button_frame,text = 'P',command =(lambda: button('P',butp)),width = 3)
        butp.pack(side = LEFT)
        butq = Button(button_frame,text = 'Q',command =(lambda: button('Q',butq)),width = 3)
        butq.pack(side = LEFT)
        butr = Button(button_frame,text = 'R',command =(lambda: button('R',butr)),width = 3)
        butr.pack(side = LEFT)
        buts = Button(button_frame,text = 'S',command =(lambda: button('S',buts)),width = 3)
        buts.pack(side = LEFT)
        butt = Button(button_frame,text = 'T',command =(lambda: button('T',butt)),width = 3)
        butt.pack(side = LEFT)
        butu = Button(button_frame,text = 'U',command =(lambda: button('U',butu)),width = 3)
        butu.pack(side = LEFT)
        butv = Button(button_frame,text = 'V',command =(lambda: button('V',butv)),width = 3)
        butv.pack(side = LEFT)
        butw = Button(button_frame,text = 'W',command =(lambda: button('W',butw)),width = 3)
        butw.pack(side = LEFT)
        butx = Button(button_frame,text = 'X',command =(lambda: button('X',butx)),width = 3)
        butx.pack(side = LEFT)
        buty = Button(button_frame,text = 'Y',command =(lambda: button('Y',buty)),width = 3)
        buty.pack(side = LEFT)
        butz = Button(button_frame,text = 'Z',command =(lambda: button('Z',butz)),width = 3)
        butz.pack(side = LEFT)
        window.mainloop()
```

I need to be able to import this file and run the hangman() function, however it shows an error that Tk() is not defined. Both files are in the same folder. What I tried is :

```
from tkinter import *
import random
from hangman import * 
hangman()
```

Could you please advise on what the other script should be?

Comment: It shouldn't give error though. `from hangman import *` should be the way of importing into another script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have worked it out myself. I moved all the imports needed in the hangman file to the top of the hangman file, and in the menu file, I only used import hangman to import my script.

so my hangman file:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
def hangman():
    etc.
```

my menu:

```
from hangman import *
hangman()
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Tkinter on your computer; because it is working fine on my computer i.e using Tk(). Which python version you are using?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157717/python-3-6-4-doesnt-have-tkinter ,go through this post may be it will help you